# Missing the "Settings" tab in admin panel

Tags: admin, install, settings

I have installed Craft CMS on fortrabbit hosting provider but missing the "Settings" tab after installation (see image below). Could anyone help me what's going wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely because [allowAdminChanges](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#allowadminchanges) is set to false for the staging/production environment in the `config/general.php` file. This is generally done purposefully so that you don't run into any issues with [project config](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/project-config.html).